# Are questions about Artificial Intelligence on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Sorry to bother but, [the latest Artificial Intelligence](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66862/artificial-intelligence?referrer=jfeDDN8LBD00UE1a4lY3qw2) was closed as a "duplicate" of this site. Some of the basic qustions included:

---

**What is the difference between AI and Machine Learning?**

**What are the necessary components to make AI agent self-programming-capable?**

**What are the practical uses/limitations of Genetic Algorithms?**

**What are some of the faster variants of backpropagation for training neural networks?**

---

**So my question is:** Do these actually count as on-topic questions for this site?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While the specific questions you listed wouldn't really be good examples for *any* Stack Exchange site (they're better suited to a roundtable discussion), the subject of machine learning and AI are certainly within the scope of Data Science — http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_science.

I'd hate to see these poor examples used as a reason to exclude AI and machine learning from being on topic. So, no, most of those questions would *not* likely be good examples to ask; but, **yes, the subjects of machine learning and AI should be included within the scope of this site.** That is, in part, what we found so appealing about creating a site that *included* this subject space.