# Is this question better suited at Artificial Intelligence.SE and/or is it off-topic for this site?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[This question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/115472/is-there-meta-cognition-in-machine-learning-algorithms) of mine asks about if we have developed neural networks with meta-cognitive processes to improve its ability to learn. I wonder if this question is better suited for Artificial Intelligence.SE.

I know this meta-question is similar to [this one](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49/are-questions-about-artificial-intelligence-on-topic), but here I am referencing a different specific question, AND I am also asking if my question is better-suited for a sister site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think part of the question makes sense here but since you also mention AGI, ai.stackexchange might be more suitable. I moved the question there.